# How to create a "real" Subversion change list from Eclipse (Subversive/Subclipse)

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, subversive

My dev team is using Eclipse/Subversive and we're happily using change sets from within Eclipse.

However, we also use a third party tool that is not integrated with Eclipse.  This tool uses SVN change lists.

Sadly, it appears Subversive/Subclipse "change sets" are not "real" SVN "change lists".

Is there a way to configure Subversive/Subclipse to use "real" SVN change lists?

Is there an easy way to create an SVN "change list" from a Subversive/Subclipse "change set"?

I feel like I'm missing something obvious because much searching has not yielded any help.

The best solution I've come up with is to have a helper-script/external-tool use the output from "Extract All..." to create the SVN change list.

TIA

Answer (score 3):

I can only speak for Subclipse.

The Eclipse Synchronize view had the concept of changesets several years before Subversion itself had them and the Subclipse feature is using this.  So essentially it is an Eclipse feature that Subclipse supports.

We have looked at making this use the Subversion API so that the changesets in Eclipse could also be seen from the command line or other tools via the SVN changelist feature.  The problem is just the API's do not overlap well.  They each have features that the other's do not and there were concerns about performance.

I'd guess something could be done to make it work, but at this point it does not appear that is going to happen.

http://subclipse.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=635

Comment: Thanks.  It sounds like this really is a "major" disconnect between SVN and the plugins.  :^(